# Disable Mouse over, mouse at and others in SeleniumIDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I need some help because when i record a test on Selenium in my script appears something like "mouse over" , "mouse at" and others. I want to disable the recording of that mouse types.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a silly question... but why not just move your mouse off the browser?

Comment: Because i need it to select some fields in the form what im filling. In other webpages i do the record and that commands dont appear.